# Can't submit form

Tags: html, forms, post

For some reason my form won't submit when pressing the submit button. I've been trying to fix it for over an hour with various things, but nothings seems to fix it.

EDITED HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" id="myform">

                    <input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 name" name='name' placeholder='Naam*'/>

                    <input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 Email" name='email' placeholder='Email*'/>

                    <input type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Subject" name='subject' placeholder='Onderwerp'/>

                    <textarea type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Message" name='message' placeholder='Bericht*'></textarea>

                    <div class="cBtn col-xs-12">
                        <ul>

                            <li class="clear"><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('myform').reset();"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Leeg</a></li>

                            <li class="send"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><i class="fa fa-share"></i>Verstuur</li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: TangledDemo'; 
    $to = '-'; 

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {              
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Uw bericht is vestuurd!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Bericht niet verstuurd. Stuur een email naar -</p>'; 
    } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit']) {
    echo '<p>U heeft de anti-spam vraag verkeerd ingevuld!</p>';
    }
?>
```

But that gives me [this](https://i.imgur.com/1vLblQn.png). The Submit button refers me to the PHP page and the blue button does nothing.

Comment: `<textarea type="text"` for one thing, doesn't have a "type". and why the 2nd `</a>` ?

Comment: Make sure your tags are all properly formatted. Some of yours are mashed into each other (They don't have closing > brackets).

Comment: Please explain what you have already tried and what the result was. That will help people understand your problem better.

Comment: Thanks. Edited main post with more information.

Comment: Hint #1: `A != a`. - Hint #2: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - you will now be able to solve it yourself. Hint #3: You have typos, which I had a feeling you would, even before seeing your edit.

Comment: I don't understand any of those hints. Could you please guide me through?

Comment: seems like everyone below has given up on you. Use error reporting. visit that link I gave you. If nobody else below is offering further help, then they've made their points and moved on. *tsk tsk*

Comment: I literally have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Like I said, this is my first experience with PHP. You don't have to be a f* a$$.

Comment: *"You don't have to be a f* a$$"* - it's comments like that which makes me shy away even more from your question, which I didn't want to touch even with a 20-foot pole. Again, take it up with the answers below, since they felt so confident about it. Oh, and let them know you've made an edit; how are they supposed to know what you did and what errors you're getting? Oh that's right, you don't know how to check for errors. Well.......... I told you how and I'm the only one helping you out. So, don't give me that f* a$$ crap, because I know what that means. Want to code? Learn how to debug too.

Comment: This is my second site that I'm 'building' using a template. How am I supposed to use error reporting if I'm not getting a specific error? How should I've known that the users below didn't get a notification when I edited my OP? I'm just building this site as a small project for someone else.

Comment: because, you're *probably* not using it right. Here.... Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, you'll see a whole bunch of "undefined index" notices and possibly variables.

Comment: Thanks. That's actual help. I don't see any undefined index notices though. I don't have server access yet, so I made a new file with the code and "include("index.php");" like the comment on the Error Reporting page suggested. How do I execute it though?

Comment: you're welcome, but I find that strange that you're not getting errors. Your name input is `name='Name'` with uppercase "N", and your POST array for it is `$_POST['name']` with a lowercase "n". That should be giving you a notice. Then, you have a spelling mistake `$_POST['subect']` which goes with the input `name='Subject'`. The error reporting goes under your PHP file where you have `<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];` you'd put the code I gave you before the first POST array. Others also have mixed letter cases.

Comment: I'm so dumb for missing that. I edited the OP with what I currently have. I still have the issue with my submit button not working. Could you please look over the code and tell me what's wrong?

Comment: @Jasper I have edited my answer in response to your edit. Any progress?

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code contains the mistake:

```
<li class="send"><i class="fa fa-share" input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"></i>Verstuur</a></li>
```

Change it to:

```
<li class="send"><i class="fa fa-share"><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/></i>Verstuur</li>
```

#### EDIT

```
<li class="send"><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('myform').submit();"><i class="fa fa-share"></i>Verstuur</a></li>
```

Comment: Now it shows up as: http://i.imgur.com/1vLblQn.png The "Submit" button refers to a PHP page rather then sending. And the blue button still does nothing.

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do. If you want to remove the submit button and leave the blue one you can use `<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('myform').submit();">` instead of `<input type="submit">`. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing angular brackets as in:

```
 <li class="send"><i class="fa fa-share" input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"></i>Verstuur</a></li>
```

to

```
 <li class="send"><i class="fa fa-share"> <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"></i>Verstuur</a></li>
```

Hope it works.

**EDIT:**
After the question has been edited, I think this is what is desired:

```
<i class="fa fa-share"></i> <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Verstuur"/></li>
```

Comment: *"Hope it works."* - the keyword here was indeed "hope". OP's made an edit to their question. It's up to you now to "bring in the big one".

Comment: It doesn't help unfortunately. [This](http://i.imgur.com/IIG1Px0.png) is what I get know, with the grey button referring me to the PHP page.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
<i class="fa fa-share" input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"></i>
```

Has two tags that are mashed together. Make sure you close the `<i>` (which is deprecated. Use `<em>` instead) tag before you start your `<input type="submit">` tag.